# create a list of object with unknown properties

Tags: c#, sql, list

i am thinking of creating a list of objects that would store row records from the database. however, the columns of the database might be unknown, that means i would not know my object properties and their types. any idea on how i can achieve that. please find the below code

```
public class TTSlogobj
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }

}

 using (SqlDataReader newReader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (newReader.Read())    
                {

                    queryResult.Add(new TTSlogobj() {
                        Name = newReader["name"].ToString(),
                        Id   = Convert.ToInt16(newReader["Id"]),
                        Age  = Convert.ToInt16(newReader["Age"]),
                        address = newReader["address"].ToString(),

                    });
                }


            }
```

as being seen on the code, TTSlogobj has properties, which are the column names from the database, how can i write the TTSlogobj without knowing the columns on the database and their type. i have gone through dapper's documentation and i realized you still have to define class properties in which you want to map your column from the database to its object. i am actually looking for a tool that creates the classes properties for you just like in entity framework. but a more simpler tool than entity framework

Comment: Why you want to do that?

Comment: If you don't know what you are expecting to read from the database, how are you expecting to use it? I'm sure there will be ways you can read/reflect the information but I'm not sure how you'd practically use this, unless you use that information to populate some concrete classes.

Comment: @d219 I totally disagree - this is *such* a common thing to want to do that we wrote a library to do *just this*, that has over 2 million downloads.

Comment: Fair do's. What's the name of the library? If I find a need to use completely 'abstract' class I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably to use a tool like [dapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper/) that already does exactly that:

```
var queryResult = connection.Query<TTSlogobj >(sql, args).AsList();
```

Note that it also has mechanisms to build on top of a data-reader if you already have the command code:

```
var rowReader = SqlMapper.GetRowParser<TTSlogobj>(newReader);
while(newReader.Read())
{
    queryResult.Add(rowReader(newReader));
}
```

---

If you want to do it *without* a library, then: reflection. Typically using generics, so you'd use `typeof(T).GetProperties()` etc. The problem is that reflection is *relatively* slow, so then you get into advanced meta-programming areas to make the performance the same as it would have been if you'd written code manually, and caching areas so you can automagically re-use the strategies that you've already spent time creating. Those are two of the major things that dapper does for you, which is *why* it is useful to use a library. Dapper *also* includes a lot of code to help you *execute* queries - making parameterization easier etc.

Comment: thank you for the reply, i was also thinking about reflection but i did a little research about its performance, which was a turn down. i would take a look at your tool and hope its quite useful.

Comment: @TobiOwolawi it is indeed quite useful - it loaded (almost) all the data on this page, for example :) some usage notes are here: https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper

Comment: i have gone through dapper's documentation and i realized you still have to define object properties in which you want to map your column from the database. i am actually looking for a tool that creates the classes properties for you just like in entity framework. but more a more simpler tool than entity framwork